# Sub report is taking a lot of time for rendering

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, rdlc

I am working on SSRS using SQL 2008 r2. I have created master report with sub reports using report viewer.

Issue: For each run .rdlc report is taking almost 5-10 min time to generate report in Win form. I am using VS 2010 and VB.Net. I believe the sub report is taking a lot of time rendering.

The main SP and sub report SP is getting executed in an instant.

The report however is running fine in BIDS environment but when loading in report viewer is taking a lot of time rendering

I have tried searching many options regarding this Issue but couldn't find enough help. I am sorry If my question is not enough clear to you all.

(P.S.= I am using embedded report for Winform for VS 2010 as .rdlc and not a Web report or .rdl (2008))

Answer (score 1):

The standard "gotcha" in this scenario is that BIDS is using dataset cache files and not going back to SQL and re-running your query.

To avoid this you can either alter your parameters on each execution (invalidating the cache) or use this feature from the geniuses behind BIDS Helper:

http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Delete%20Dataset%20Cache%20Files&referringTitle=Documentation

If this is the case, the real issue is that your datasets queries are taking a long time to run.  This is usually a SQL or database design issue, not SSRS.

Comment: BIDS Helper is a great tool

Comment: Hi Mike, Thank you for your reply. I think for me is not the case as I am using embedded report in Winform and not as Web report. Also I am using as .rdlc in VS2010 and not .rdl(2008). Any help in this Issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Well I'm trying to help but you seem to prefer guesswork... You can easily find out if this is your issue by installing BIDS Helper and trying that feature.  It will tell you if it found any dataset cache files.